# Allow one handler for Runnable?

Tags: android, admob, android-handler

Im trying to implement Interstitial Ads in my app. Im using a handler with postDelayed to delay the showing of the interstitial ad by 10 seconds.

My small app uses fragments. I have fragment 1 which contains a button to go to fragment 2 via fragment replacement transaction.

A problem im having is multiple instances of the same task being made which results into more than 1 interstitial ad showing (which is not good). This happens if you go into fragment 2, press back and then go into fragment 2 again.

What I want is a way to only allow a single handler (1 message) for this runnable. To prevent multiple ads from appearing

My main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ViewGroup container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            container = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container);
            if(container != null)
            {
                Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(container.getId(), fragment1, Fragment1.class.getName());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        int isAvaiable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(isAvaiable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            Log.d("TEST", "GPS IS OK");
        }
        else if(isAvaiable == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING || 
                isAvaiable == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED || 
                isAvaiable == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED)
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvaiable, this, 10).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Fragment 1

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private Button bFragmentB;
    private ViewGroup container;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        this.container = container;
        bFragmentB = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bFragmentB);
        bFragmentB.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId())
        {
        case R.id.bFragmentB:
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(container.getId(),new Fragment2(),Fragment2.class.getName());
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment 2 (which contains the interstitial ad)

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
{
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private  InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .build();

        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
          {
              @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() 
            {
                  handler.postDelayed(showInterstitialAd, 10000);
            }
          });
    }

    private Runnable showInterstitialAd = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            interstitialAd.show();  
        }
    };
}
```

**Here is a summary of the things I have tried but did not work**

On fragment B onDestroy I have this code

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(showInterstitialAd);
}
```

Still resulted in more than 1 instance of the task (2 ads appearing). Also is not good if the screen rotates anyway because the task would be destroyed from my understanding.

**Another attempt at things**

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() 
    {
        if(!handler.hasMessages(1))
        {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            handler.postDelayed(showInterstitialAd, 10000);
        }
        //else do nothing
    }
});
```

This one was pretty stupid considering a new hander object is made at the start so it would not have a message to begin with :D. The idea was to have message in the queue of 1 and if it sees 1 existing already then do not start another handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your old fragment2 is not getting full destryoed/GC'ed yet.

Since we are trying to get hold of the existing `callback`, which we created in old fragment, we need to save a reference to it, so we can delete it from handler message queue. You can do this by saving it in Application level global.

```
public class Global extends Application {
  public Runnable oldshowInterstitialAd = null;
}
```

update your manifest `Application` with

```
<application android:name=".Global"
```

add the `handler.removeCallbacks(oldshowInterstitialAd);` just before posting a new one.

```
public void onAdLoaded() 
{
    handler.removeCallbacks(((Global)getApplicationContext()).oldshowInterstitialAd);
    handler.postDelayed(showInterstitialAd, 10000);
    ((Global)getApplicationContext()).oldshowInterstitialAd = showInterstitialAd;
}
```

saving a reference to old fragment's member may hinder its GC'ing, but we loose the reference anyways as we update `oldshowInterstitialAd` with newer one.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the problem still persists after adding the line